# Does 50-mouse-acceleration.conf have the ability to change mousepad settings on hardware level?

Tags: scripts, mouse, touchpad, 16.10

The touchpad on my laptop behaved weirdly, so I decided to disable acceleration (without knowing what it is exactly), using [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Mouse_acceleration#Disabling_mouse_acceleration) guide. 
The issues with my mouse cursor resolved, and because of this, I had the opportunity to even notice what pointer acceleration is (because it wasn't turned off by this script)

I started up my windows dual boot, and noticed that the mouse behaves exactly the same as on Ubuntu 16.10.

This makes me conclude that either I changed mouse settings on hardware level with this tweak, or I attained the (unsuspected) default mouse behaviour.

To test this, I would like to know whether the tweaks are applied on every boot, or if they are somehow applied forever, and transferring the 50-mouse-acceleration.conf file out of its folder or commenting our the code, would not be enough to revert the settings to how they used to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing a configuration file such as that will not tweak the mouse on a hardware level. Being an X Configuration File, it will be read every time the X server starts up, setting the mouse acceleration settings. If you turned it off in your Ubuntu system, and your Windows system is behaving the same, then one can likely safely conclude that Windows by default isn't using mouse acceleration, or happens to have it set very closely to how it was set on your Ubuntu system.

Comment: Oh. I was afraid that the tweak did something to my windows mouse.  Do you have any idea why this script didnt remove mouse acceleration, but just made my mouse behave "normal". I mean, I like it this way, I was just wondering if some specific command did it, and others were obsolete or something. My fear is that some opposing commands in different sides of the system create an anomaly, and this behaviour is actually not "gramatically correct", Since it doesnt do what it's supposed to do, regardless of the outcome being desirable Tnx!

Comment: "Correct" behavior is hard to define. If you can configure it, then there is likely not a "correct" behavior. You don't have to worry about one system affecting the other, though, since Linux and Windows use completely different configuration files to set how hardware input is interpreted. The only way to change how the hardware itself works without getting a new touchpad would be to get a different driver. Which still wouldn't change the hardware, just the interpretation. In this case, there probably wasn't a "normal" setting. Linux just used one default and windows a different default.